# How to debug app in compatibility mode on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, debugging, compatibility, ios7

So, iOS 7 was released and a lot of our users have already upgraded, even though we officially do not support iOS 7 and have asked everyone not to upgrade. Right now the app runs in compatibility mode and there are lots of issues being reported by our users. The problem is that I do not know how to debug in compatibility mode, so some of these issues are really hard to fix. I tried to Google for it, but so far I've had no luck.

How can I debug an app on iOS 7 in compatibility mode?

Comment: Is really a problem. I never figured out how to debug an iOS6 build on iOS7.

Comment: @Andrea, then you'll be happy to hear that I found a way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. This is what I did:

1. Install Xcode 5 from App Store. (Skip this step if it's already installed.)
2. Make sure you can deploy to your iOS 7 device from Xcode 5.
3. Download Xcode 4 from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).
4. Open the dmg.
5. Drag Xcode 4 to some other location than Applications, e.g. Documents.
6. Rename that copy to something other than Xcode, e.g. Xcode 4.
7. Drag the renamed copy to Applications.
8. Start Xcode 4 and deploy to your iOS 7 device.
9. The app is now being debugged in compatibility mode on iOS 7.

These are the steps that I used and they worked for me. I'm sure there are other variations that will work. The key seems to be to have Xcode 4 and 5 installed side by side. Maybe you can even uninstall Xcode 5 afterwards, but I didn't test this, since I primarily use Xcode 5. It seems like Xcode 5 enables deployment to iOS 7 and after it's enabled Xcode 4 is also able to deploy to iOS 7.