# Getting Keyboard of ios6 in ios7 app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios7

When i'am running my app using ios7 i faces two problems:

1)Its status bar comes on UI.I have implemented the code in BoolDidFinishLaunching,which i got from google search but still problem exist the UI distorted from bottom of it.

2)Secondly,i am getting the same keyboard in ios7.Although ios7 has its own default keyboard.

Comment: @pratikbhiyani: what's not possible....?

Comment: ios 6 keyboard in ios 7

Answer (score 2):

Your app is working in compatibility mode, unless you don't compile it under xCode5 iOS7, so this is the default behavior, plus there are many issues being reported. To debug your app in compatibility mode on iOS7 check this question in SO:

[How to debug app in compatibility mode on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959986/how-to-debug-app-in-compatibility-mode-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

For you issue number 1 i face same problem and here is its solution

[iOS 7 - Status bar overlaps the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view/19044820#19044820)

For you issue number 2 you have to compile your code through xcode 5 only then keyboard and search bar and other UI components of iOS 7 will reflect.