# Getting ios6 keyboard in ios 7 app

Tags: ios6, ios7, keyboard, xcode5

I have checked [Getting Keyboard of ios6 in ios7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088345/getting-keyboard-of-ios6-in-ios7-app) but it does not answer my problem.

I have an app compiled in Xcode 5.0.2 using Base SDK IOS 7.0 and Deployment Target IOS 6.0. When I launched the app in an ios 7 device and select a TextField, I get the an ios 6 keyboard i.e. not the themed keyboard of ios 7.

However, in ios 7 simulator, it works fine.

Any help?

Comment: Hello Ketan, were you able to solve this issue ? we are having the same problem. Thanks Frank

Comment: @user485083 No, it appears to be a bug in `iOS` 7. When I reboot the phone and reinstalled the app, sometimes it works fine.